# JQuery slideToggle display type

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using a jQuery slideToggle to show a hidden table row but it sets the display style to block and I need to to display table-row. any ideas how i could accomplish this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I figured out a solution to this problem - check if the display has been set to block (if the element has been toggled to be shown) and if so set to desired display type.

```
$('a.btn').on('click', function() {
    $('div.myDiv').slideToggle(200, function() {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') $(this).css('display', 'table-row'); // enter desired display type
    });
});
```

Comment: note the question, he asked how to set the inline style to table-row , not inline-block -1

Comment: @redsquare Note my code- the commented section that says "enter desired display type". That's pretty weak to downvote the only working solution to this question.

Comment: was weak to download mine which satisfied the question...anyway upvoted you

Comment: @redsquare Thanks, I appreciate it. The reason I downvoted yours was because I actually tried it. The problem with your answer is that `slidetoggle()` shows AND hides, but with your modification, it can't hide.

Answer (score 4):

inorganik's solution is almost working. But you also need to set the `step` callback to change `block` to `table-row`.

```
        $('row-selector-here').slideToggle({
            duration: 'fast',
            step: function() {
                if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
                    $(this).css('display', 'table-row');
                }
            },
            complete: function() {
                if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
                    $(this).css('display', 'table-row');
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This also works for when setting display to `flex` rather than `table-row`.  I also had to add another if clause to detect when it sets it to `none`, and sets it to `''` so external css could apply without being overridden (jquery messes with the element's css directly in the html, which overrides css anywhere, unless `!important` is used, which I didn't want to use).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the callback to change this

```
$('#tableRowId').slideToggle( function(){
   $(this).css('display', 'table-row');
});
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it sets the display style to table-row every time, when half the time you really want it to be hidden.

Comment: Same problem, had to downvote it. `slideToggle()` shows and hides, this makes it so it can't hide. Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [bug](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4096) (also [here](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/2185)).  with jQuery `slideToggle`.  There isn't any way to use `slideToggle` and have it properly preserve the display style.  You can apply the display style with a callback when the animation completes, but that may not achieve the effect you desire.

Comment: It's worth noting that the bug report says using simply .toggle() works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

just add this code to callback function

`$(this).css('display','');`