# jQuery slideToggle() Issues - Change display:block to display:inline-table?

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I'm using jQuery's slideToggle() function to control the expand/collapse feature of my website. Currently, I only have one page which has been developed upon before I implement it across the site; [here it is](http://dylricho.com/devices/phones/htc/one-s.php).

By default, jQuery slideToggle() uses **display="block"** which isn't helping me. I'd like to make it use **display="inline-table"** instead when a panel is expanded, and revert back to **display="none"** when the same panel is collapsed.

There are a few settings I've applied to the CSS to make sure that the layout is how I want it to be:

```
.specs {
    width: 930px;
    height: 100px;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: none;
}
```

The height property is used to ensure that all of the icons within the panels are fully viewable. Removing this will cause smaller panels like 'Memory' to cut off half of the icon.

While collapsed, the panels are set to **display="none"** to make sure they don't affect the layout. However, upon expanding, they need to be set to **display="inline-table"** to bypass some alignment issues which you can currently see when looking at panels like 'Web Browsing' and 'Rear Camera' (basically, the lists overlap the DIVs below, and the *inline-table* setting fixes that).

As soon as I'm able to fix this issue, I can move on to implement this design into other pages.

P.S. - Currently in use, is [Redsquare's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266221/jquery-slidetoggle-display-type), so expanding is fine, but they don't want to collapse.

Thank you,
Dylan.

Comment: `Note: The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.`

Comment: @Bondye This is in Chrome, Firefox and IE9. All my webpages use the HTML5 doctype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me. Use `min-height` instead of `height`

```
.specs {
    width: 930px;
    /*min-height: 100px; CHECK UPDATE */
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: none;
}
```

**UPDATE:** See it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/LLQyV/1/

Try this.  Remove min-height from the CSS.

In your HTML enclose each spec in a div classed as toggleContainer like so (I duplicated your general category and added various specs to each one.)

```
<!-- General -->
<div class="toggleContainer">
<div class="spec-cat">
<div class="spec-cat-content" id="general"><a href="#general">General</a>
<span class="spec-cat-desc"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="specs" id="sec1">
    <ul>
        <li>Manufactured by HTC</li>
        <li>Also known as HTC Ville and HTC Z520e</li>
        <li>Released in March 2012</li>
        <li>£429 (GBP); $399 (USD)</li>
        <li>Manufactured by HTC</li>
        <li>Also known as HTC Ville and HTC Z520e</li>
        <li>Released in March 2012</li>
        <li>£429 (GBP); $399 (USD)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<!-- General -->
<div class="toggleContainer">
<div class="spec-cat">
<div class="spec-cat-content" id="general"><a href="#general">General</a>
<span class="spec-cat-desc"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="specs" id="sec1">
    <ul>
        <li>£429 (GBP); $399 (USD)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<!-- General -->
<div class="toggleContainer">
<div class="spec-cat">
<div class="spec-cat-content" id="general"><a href="#general">General</a>
<span class="spec-cat-desc"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="specs" id="sec1">
    <ul>
        <li>Manufactured by HTC</li>
        <li>Also known as HTC Ville and HTC Z520e</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Then in your JS file do this (I combined all your onclick='toggle' calls into this)

```
$(function() {
    $(".toggleContainer").each(function() {
        //store the .specs height to an unchanging attribute
        $(this).find(".specs").attr("specHeight", $(this).find(".specs").height());

        //when the cat is clicked, expand or collapse the spec
        $(this).find(".spec-cat-content").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //find spec for current toggleContainer that contains this category toggle button
            var spec = $(this).parent().parent().find(".specs");

            //check to see if the spec is displayed.
            if ($(spec).css("display") == "none") {
                //if it isn't then animate to specHeight attr and display block                $(spec).height(0);
                $(spec).css("display","block");
                var newHeight=$(spec).attr("specHeight");
                if(newHeight<100)
                    newHeight=100;
                $(spec).animate({height:newHeight},400);
            }
            else {
                //if it is, then animate to 0 height, and display:none
                $(spec).animate({height:0},400,function(){$(spec).css("display","none");});

            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Hi Michael. I've now added the code to all categories on the page. `height` is used because the 'Memory' category doesn't display the full icon otherwise. As you should now be able to see, the categories don't collapse once clicked. I'm trying to fix that.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that using `min-height` seems to make the slide transition somewhat jerky.

Comment: Check the update.  This should help you get where your are trying to go.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that. Could you explain why there are `specheight` attributes in the HTML code? I've never seen custom attributes used before. Also, [here](http://dylricho.com/archive/learning/jQuery/index.htm) is the above coding in action. I'm not sure if you experience it, but I notice a slight delay with the icons moving sometimes.

Comment: `specheight` is just an easy way to keep the orginal height accessible after you change it.  A lot of jQuery plugins use custom attributes. I do notice the icons jump after a short period.  I believe that's caused by the default margin of `ul`...if you add `margin:0;` to `.specs ul` you should see it go away.

Comment: I see. Thank you for explaining everything to me, and for the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use slideToggle() built-in function,create function of your own.

Use .toggleClass() : http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Something like this:

css:

```
.DisplayNone{
   display: none;
}

.DisplayInlineTable{
   display: inline-table;
}
```

then create onclick event:

jquery:

```
$(parent).click(function(){
   $(child).toggleClass("DisplayInlineTable").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this method out too, which you can still access if you want to uncomment the necessary coding. I did think about using this method, but I was unsure on how to implement a sliding animation; preferably one that goes in both directions.